# cannot add remote (local on same network) git repo

Tags: git

I have a linux server setup on the same network and when I try to add the repo to my computer I get this error message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.1.128:: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am using git tower on mac and the repository url looks like this:

```
ssh://linux@192.168.1.128:/var/www/gitrepo/cm_main.git
```

update: (error message i got after removing ssh://

```
Pushing to linux@192.168.1.128:/var/www/gitrepo/cm_main.git
Counting objects: 965, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects:   0% (1/946)   
Compressing objects:   1% (10/946)   
...
Compressing objects:  99% (937/946)   
Compressing objects: 100% (946/946)   
Compressing objects: 100% (946/946), done.
Writing objects:   0% (1/965)   
Writing objects:   1% (10/965)   
Writing objects:   2% (20/965)   
Writing objects:   3% (29/965)   
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/var/www/gitrepo/cm_main.git/.git/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'linux@192.168.1.128:/var/www/gitrepo/cm_main.git'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dropping the ssh:// prefix.

Comment: i did that but got another error. look above under update with the error message.

Comment: never mind, thanks! i got it to work i just had to chmod the directory.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you figured it out :-)!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `ssh://` syntax, you need to make it `ssh://user@host/path/to/repo`. The colon in your version is wrong.

Otherwise, if you are not using explicit protocol, it is `user@host:/path/to/repo`, so your second version should work. The error message you receive shows that there is a completely different problem:

```
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/var/www/gitrepo/cm_main.git/.git/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
```

So the user you are trying to push with (`linux`) does not have write access rights in the remote repository folder.